# How to make transitions between images in canvas (unity)

Tags: c#, unity

So I have 3 same images, but with different colors which I want to cycle in my menu. They are only with different hue/saturations and I want them to slowly reduce their alpha 1 by 1 so that the one behind pops up and then restart the cycle.

I'm trying to set a public image and reduce it's alpha, but it's not smooth.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be with a looping animation (using the [Animation Editor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html)) but I gather from your description of "public image" that you're trying to do this through code? Can you show us the code you've been using so far? We may be able to show you where to fix the smoothness issue.

Comment: as @DMGregory said, there are number of ways to do that. If you can show your code so members can modify that for your ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please more describle your problems by picture or your code but
you can easily smooth it by `Time.deltatime` in your code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Collections;

    public class FadeOut: MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Image FadePanel;

        void Update ()
        {
            Color newColor = FadePanel.color;
            newColor.a -= 1*Time.deltaTime;
            FadePanel.color = newColor;
        }
    }
```

or you can Find your Image by FindGameObjectWithTag

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ReduceAlpha: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Image healthImage = GameObject.Find("GameObject").GetComponent<Image>();
        Color newColor = healthImage.color;
        newColor.a -= 1*Time.deltaTime;
        healthImage.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense, just for information, provided answer by brother **smkplus** is really not that optimized.

- It is in `Update` due to that, these lines will be executed per frame with and without reason.
- In 2nd option, `GameObject.Find` is in `Update`, believe me or not, it is a crime bro :)

I'd suggest to use Unity's gift `Coroutine` for that.

Here is an example code,

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Help8 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image _image;
    public float _fadeSpeed = 0.05f;

    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine (Fadeout (_image, _fadeSpeed));
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // Update is empty for this purpose.
    }

    // You can use it for multiple images, just pass that image.
    IEnumerator Fadeout (Image image, float speed)
    {
        // Will run only until image's alpha becomes completely 0, will stop after that.
        while (image.color.a > 0) {

            // You can replace WaitForEndOfFrame with WaitForSeconds.
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
            Color colorWithNewAlpha = image.color;
            colorWithNewAlpha.a -= speed;
            image.color = colorWithNewAlpha;
        }
    }
}
```